# Getting CORS error only when running django app through docker-compose

Tags: reactjs, django, docker, axios

I have a Django backend app using Django-rest-framework. Currently, I'm developing the frontend with React using Axios to make HTTP requests.

Whenever I run my app using `python manage.py runserver` and make a request from the React client, I get the expected response.

Nevertheless, if I start my app using docker-compose, I get the *No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource* response.

This is my docker-compose.yaml

```
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/docker/volumes/mobilequoter/db/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - ${DB_PORT}:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}
  web:
    build: .
    command: gunicorn mobilequoter.wsgi --bind 0.0.0.0:${PORT}
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - 8000:${PORT}
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=db
      - DB_PORT=5432
    depends_on:
      - db
```

This is is my settings.py (with the settings related to CORS:

```
handler = EnvHandler()

SECRET_KEY = handler.SECRET_KEY
DEBUG = handler.DEBUG
ALLOWED_HOSTS = handler.ALLOWED_HOSTS
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = handler.CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS
SHELL_PLUS = 'ipython'

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    #  third party
    'rest_framework',
    'drf_yasg',
    'storages',
    'django_extensions',
    'corsheaders',

    #  local
    'mobilequoter.helper',
    'mobilequoter.authentication',
    'mobilequoter.client',
    'mobilequoter.quote',
    'mobilequoter.sale',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

This are my env vars related to hosts:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS=127.0.0.1,localhost
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS=http://127.0.0.1:3000,http://localhost:3000
```

This is my axios client:

```
import axios from "axios";

const axiosClient = axios.create({ baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL });

export default axiosClient;
```

```
REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL=http://localhost:8000/api/
```

This is where I make the request:

```
import axiosClient from "../../../config/axios";
import { login, logout } from "../slices/auth";

export const loginAction = (data) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const response = await axiosClient.post("auth/access/", data);
    console.log(response.data);
    dispatch(login(response.data));
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(err);
  }
};

export const logoutAction = () => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch(logout());
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(err);
  }
};
```

This is what I get when on docker-compose
[image]

This is what I get with runserver
[image]

Comment: The validation for the preflight request's response can be quite fussy. Are you able to log the response of the preflight `OPTIONS` request? For example, the Allow-Origin header must match exactly (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://foo.bar.org`) and cannot be a list of values. And, is the request method allowed (`Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE`)?

Comment: Reading the error image more carefully, there is no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header at all. Can you try removing the `127.0.0.1` values?